# Preload image urls using new Image()

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to preload or prefetch remote images in my photo gallery but it seems that `new Image()` conflicts with the nextjs's `next/image`.

This code works fine before(using CRA) I migrated to nextjs.

```
 const img = new Image();
 img.src = photoToPreload.largeUrl;
```

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just rename the import for next/image, (`import RenamedImage from 'next/image'`) and it will resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try giving Next.js's version of `Image` a nonconflicting alias (or the other way around with your custom `Image` import):

```js
// CommonJS style
const { default: NextImage } = require("next/image");
```

```js
// ES module style
import NextImage from "next/image";

// alternatively
import { default as NextImage } from "next/image";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change imported name of `next/image` to another name like

```
import NextImage from 'next/image'
```

That would help you to reserve the name `Image` for your original stuff

But I think you can achieve the same thing with `next/image` in a better way

You just add [`priority`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority) prop to your `NextImage`

```
<NextImage {...otherProps} priority={true}/>
```

It will generate [`preload` link](https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/#preload-overview) to preload your image as an important resource. Furthermore, you can leverage other optimization stuff in `next/image` package.

Comment: I think what OP is trying to do is to pre-load a series of images rather than a single image.

Comment: It does not matter, if it's a single image or multiple images with this approach though @Beaumont

Answer (score 1):

To prefetch new images of the Carousel, you can render an invisible Image component with the src of the next image and NextJS will preload it to you and will be ready when the user swipe to the next slide. If your carousel is above-the-fold, make sure to add priority to the first slide also.

```
import NextImage from 'next/image'
() => {
  return (
    <div className="relative w-[300px]">
      <NextImage
        src={Screens[activeScreenIdx]}
        placeholder="blur"
        quality={100}
        layout="fill"
        objectFit="contain"
        sizes="350px"
      />
    {/* prefetch next image */}
      <NextImage
        {/* ..% Screen.length to avoid going out boundary */}
        src={Screens[(activeScreenIdx + 1) % Screens.length]}
        placeholder="blur"
        className="invisible" {/* just for preloading purposes */}
        quality={100}
        layout="fill"
        objectFit="contain"
        sizes="350px"
      />
    </div>
 )
}
```